rylr498 receiver problem
I have a problem receiving heart rate message tranmission data from the reciever. I was able ot transmit the data from the trasnmitter but I am unavke to recieve the data from the reciever side. This is the code for the transmitter and reciever respectively
transmitter code:
#include <PulseSensorPlayground.h> // Include the PulseSensor library

String lora_band = "490000000";  // enter band as per your country
String lora_networkid = "5";     // enter Lora Network ID
String lora_address = "1";        // enter Lora address
String lora_RX_address = "2";     // enter Lora RX address
int Threshold = 550;           // Determine which Signal to "count as a beat" and which to ignore

PulseSensorPlayground pulseSensor;  // Creates an object
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay(1500);
  Serial.println("AT+BAND=" + lora_band);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+ADDRESS=" + lora_address);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+NETWORKID=" + lora_networkid);
  delay(1500);
  
  // Initialize PulseSensor
  pulseSensor.analogInput(A0); // Assuming your pulse sensor is connected to analog pin A1
  pulseSensor.blinkOnPulse(LED_BUILTIN); // Blink onboard LED with heartbeat
  pulseSensor.setThreshold(Threshold);
  

  // Double-check if PulseSensor object was created and began seeing a signal
  if (pulseSensor.begin()) {
    Serial.println("PulseSensor object created!");
  }
}

void loop() {
  int myBPM = pulseSensor.getBeatsPerMinute(); // Calculate BPM
  
  if (pulseSensor.sawStartOfBeat()) { // Constantly test if a beat happened
    Serial.println("♥  A HeartBeat Happened ! "); // If true, print a message
    Serial.print("BPM: ");
    Serial.println(myBPM); // Print the BPM value
    Serial.println("AT+SEND=" + lora_RX_address + ",2,H" + String(myBPM)); // Send a LoRa message when a heartbeat is detected
  }

  // You can add additional LoRa message sending logic here, depending on your requirements

  delay(20); // Small delay to avoid excessive CPU usage
}

receiver code:
String lora_band = "490000000";   // Enter band as per your country
String lora_networkid = "5";     // Enter Lora Network ID
String lora_address = "2";        // Enter Lora address (receiver address)
String lora_RX_address = "1";     // Enter Lora RX address

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(57600);
  delay(1500);
  Serial.println("AT+BAND=" + lora_band);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+ADDRESS=" + lora_address);
  delay(500);
  Serial.println("AT+NETWORKID=" + lora_networkid);
  delay(1500);
}

void loop() {
  if (Serial.available() > 0) { // Check if data is available to read from LoRa module
    String receivedData = Serial.readStringUntil('\n'); // Read the incoming data until newline character
    if (receivedData.startsWith("AT+SEND=")) { // Check if received data starts with "AT+SEND="
      String message = receivedData.substring(8); // Extract message (excluding "AT+SEND=")
      Serial.println("Received message: " + message);
    }
  }
  delay(20); // Small delay to avoid excessive CPU usage
}

Kindly assist me on this problem.

How did you connect your Lora module with your Arduino Nano? Serial.print() send the data to your Serial Monitor, it does not send to the serial port of the Lora module, you will need SoftwareSerial library for communication with Lora module, on both the transmitter and the receiver.

I was able ot transmit the data from the trasnmitter ... how do you know this?

I connected the tx to rx and rx to tx in the arduino nano for reciever and transmitter. i used 4.7k and 10k ohm pull up resistor to make sure the voltage is 3.3v.

The tx light glows each time the heartbeat reading is detected.
